# Struggling to get the Android View in my Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, github

I've cloned a git project from [here](https://github.com/Navigine/Android-SDK) (Navigine SDK), but it doesn't seem to give me the Android View when I clone it in Android Studio (3.6.1).

[image: Project View]

Now obviously here you usually get the Android view at the bottom, which should show the java files in the App Folder in the NavigeneDemo Folder. But There's no such view here and I'm not sure why, I've tried looking online but whenever I search Android View I can't seem to get any answer or question that's similar to my problem.

[image: Android View?]

I have tried just downloading the ZIP file from the GIT and opening just the NavigeneDemo folder inside the Android-SDK project, but when I do that it doesn't work since it needs the other files that are in the Android-SDK project such as ".idea", ".grade", "libs" etc.

I'm sure this is just a simple problem, the Git project I'm using is supposed to have Android Studio compatibility, so maybe I'm just not doing something right, any answers or feedback are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the NavigineDemo folder inside Android-SDK and build it, and also  it doesn’t depend from external files and folders like libs, etc.

Otherwise here is the solutions that could be helpful for you, if you will get some problems:

1) Try creating a new project to see if **Android Project View** is available. If it is, try to open NavigineDemo.

2) Go to **Preferences** > **Plugins** and enable Android Support, at a minimum.
Now you should have "Android" option in the Project View.

3) Try to build project using **gradle** and install using adb.

If you will have more questions try connect with Navigine [support team](https://navigine.com/contacts/)

Comment: Thank you very much Pavel :)